# execve - No such file or directory?

Tags: c, linux, execve

I'm having some problems with execve. I'm trying to make a shell that can function just like the bash shell, but I have problems with the forked child executing a command. Here is what I have for the child. cmd is a char * with the command that the user typed in. However, when I run this program, I get this error from perror:

```
execve error: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried the program with a simple ls, and it should make path="/bin/ls" and execute it (I have confirmed this is where my ls command is) but it still complains. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
if(pid == 0)
{
    // Parse the command
    char * word = strtok(cmd, " ");
    char path[128] = "/bin/";
    strcat(path, word);

    // Execute the process
    char * newenvp[] = { NULL };
    char * newargv[] = { path, NULL };
    ret = execve(path, newargv, newenvp);

    if(ret == -1)
        perror("execve error");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `path` contains what you think it does?  Especially given that `strtok()` is somewhat notoriously annoying in the way it operates, and can easily produce garbage if you don't play precisely by its rules?

Comment: Nothing wrong that I can see. Why not throw in a `printf()` to display the final contents of `path` to make sure the `strtok` is doing the right thing -- the `execve` call itself looks fine.

Comment: Why are you setting the environment to empty?  You should probably use plain `execv()` to use your current environment, or pass `environ` as the third argument to `execve()`.  I doubt if this is the source of your problem, but it is better practice.  (Also, it is often sensible to use `execv(newargv[0], newargv);` or `execve(newargv[0], newargv, environ);`.  And there's no point in testing the return status of any of the `exec*()` functions: if it returned, it failed; if it succeeds, it doesn't return.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *first* thing I would do would be to insert:

```
printf ("[%s]\n", path);
```

before the call to `execve`. That should confirm that the executable is what you think it is.

That code of yours looks okay *as long as* the input you're feeding into it is correct and the executable actually *is* available. For example, the following complete program works fine on my Debian box:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        char * word = strtok (argv[1], " ");
        char path[128] = "/bin/";
        strcat (path, word);

        char * newenvp[] = { NULL };
        char * newargv[] = { path, NULL };
        printf ("[%s]\n", path);
        int ret = execve (path, newargv, newenvp);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("execve error");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputting, when I run `./testprog ls`, something along the lines of:

```
[/bin/ls]
kidsshares.ods  paxwords    birthdays    homeloantracking.gnumeric
shares2011.ods  backup0.sh  development  lexar
accounts.ods    backup1.sh  photos       testprog.c
testprog
```

Comment: Found the problem, thanks for the suggestion! I was printing out my path with write(), which ignored the fact that I was missing my null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually travel through the fileystem to find the correct binary, there is `execlp` (with an additional *p*).
From the manpage:

> The  **execlp**(),  **execvp**(), and **execvpe**() functions duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified
>   filename does not contain a slash (/) character.  The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory  pathnames  specified in the **PATH** environment variable.  If this variable isn't defined, the path list defaults to the current directory followed by the list of directories returned by confstr(_CS_PATH).  (This confstr(3) call typically returns the value "/bin:/usr/bin".) [...]