# execve() failing inspite of correct argv vector

Tags: c, shell, process, operating-system, execve

I'm trying to implement a basic shell using the given below code. It is throwing an error when trying to load and run a non-builtin command.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <readline/readline.h>
    #include <readline/history.h>

    #define MAXARGS 10

    /* Parse input command */ 
    /* return 1 if background process */
    /* return 0 if foreground process */

    int parse_line(char *cmd, char **argv)
    {
        int bg;         /* background or foreground process */
        int argc;       /* number of arguments to be passed to exec */
        char *delim;    /* points to first space occurence in cmd */

        /* Ignore leading spaces in cmd */
        while(*cmd && (*cmd == ' '))
        {
            cmd++;
        }

        /* Build argv list */
        argc = 0;
        while((delim = strchr(cmd, ' ')))
        {
            *delim = '\0';  /* To NULL terminate the token pointer */
            argv[argc++] = cmd;
            cmd = ++delim;
            /* Ignore leading spaces in cmd after token */
            while(*cmd && (*cmd == ' '))
            {
                cmd++;
            }
        }
        /* argv is NULL terminated */
        argv[argc] = NULL;

        int i = 0;

        /* Blank command */
        if(argc == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        /* If background process, return 1 and truncate & from cmd */
        if((bg = (*argv[argc - 1]) == '&'))
        {
            argv[--argc] = NULL;
        }

        return bg;
    }

    int builtin_cmd(char **argv)
    {
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], "exit")) /* quit command */
            exit(0);
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], "&"))
            return 1;               /* Ignore singleton & */
        
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char cwd[PATH_MAX]; /* current directory */
        char *cmd;
        char *argv[MAXARGS];
        char *environ[] = { NULL };
        int i = 0;
        pid_t pid;
        int status, bg;

        while(1) 
        {
            if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) 
            {
                /* Print prompt and read command */
                printf("%s", cwd);
            } 
            else 
            {
                printf("cwd error\n");
                return 1;
            }

            cmd = readline(": ");
            cmd = (char*)realloc(cmd, sizeof(char)*strlen(cmd));
            /* last character is set to ' ' to parse properly */
            cmd[strlen(cmd)] = ' ';
            bg = parse_line(cmd, argv);

            /* Evaluate command */
            /* Ignore blank command */
            if(argv[0] == NULL)
                return 1;

            /* Fork and exec if not builtin command */
            if(!builtin_cmd(argv))
            {
                if((pid = fork()) == 0)
                {
                    /* Load image of executable in child process */
                    if(execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        while(argv[i] != NULL)
                        {
                            printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                            i++;
                        } 
                        printf("execve error\n");
                        free(cmd);
                        return 1;
                    }
                }

                if(pid > 0)
                {
                    /* Shell waits for foreground process to terminate */
                    if(!bg)
                    {
                        if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
                        {
                            printf("waitpid error\n");
                            free(cmd);
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

For some reason, the execve() command keeps failing. This is my console output:
[image]

I'm passing the correct parameters to the execve function and the argv vector seems to have the correct parameters and is NULL terminated. I'm unable to spot the error here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change `printf("execve error\n")` to `fprintf(stderr, "execve error: %s\n", strerror(errno));`  Add `#include <string.h>` and `#include <errno.h>` to the top of the file. Recompile, re-run. Does that reveal what the problem is?

Comment: Probable cause:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158782/execve-no-such-file-or-directory  Read the second answer...

Comment: Check whether inputting `/bin/ls -lha` does work.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm passing the correct parameters to the execve function

No, you are not. `execve()` will *not* search your `$PATH`, and so correctly fails (unless there is an `ls` executeable file in your current directory).

If you want to search `$PATH`, use `execvpe()` or you must search the `$PATH` yourself and try calling `execvp()` for each possible candidate in a loop.